# Is there a way to know exactly how much time does it take to apply compositing nodes to each frame?

Tags: add-on, compositing-nodes

Is there any kind of add-on or method that calculates the delay of every compositing process? It'd be love to know how much time does it take to apply every node so, e.g you can decide whether it's a good idea to defocus in compositing or via depth of field. Thank you.

Comment: Hard to tell, it depends on so many factors likely the size of the image and the capabilities of your particluar hardware. Measure the time yourself.

Comment: @susu I know, but I'm talking about the time when it's already rendered. I mean the difference total time - render time = compositing time. Thank you so much for taking your time to awnser me :)

Comment: There are certain processes that are computationally more intensive than others, like blurs (blur, glow, defocus, motion blur, etc). But I believe the question should not be about time, but about the results you are after. Using depth of field in the camera yields a very different result than defocusing on the compositor.